# Calculus of constructions, type-in-type and recursion

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory, dependent-types, calculus-of-constructions

Does adding type-in-type to the calculus of constructions lead to (general) recursion? Such that one can write the Y combinator.

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://lists.seas.upenn.edu/pipermail/types-list/2008/001226.html) by Herman Geuvers to a similar question useful. And the whole thread is very illuminating.

Comment: @AntonTrunov you might as well turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you can not write the Y-combinator but only "looping" combinators. So you can not write (general) recursive functions in type-in-type.